# How to use SynonymFilterFactory in Solr?

Tags: solr

I'm trying to execute synonym filtering at query time so that if I search for X, results for Y also show up.

I go to where Solr is being run, edit the .txt file and add X, Y on a new line.

This does not work. I check the schema and I see:

```
<analyzer type="query">
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
Assessing configuration files

**tomcat6/Catalina/localhost** seems to point to the correct location

```
<Context docBase="/data/solr/solr.war" debug="0" privileged="true" allowLinking="true" crossContext="true">
  <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/data/solr" override="true" />
</Context>
```

Also, in the Solr admin I see this. What does cwd mean?

```
cwd=/usr/share/tomcat6 SolrHome=/data/solr/
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the SynonymFilterFactory only at index time, not query time. There are some subtle but well-understood problems with synonyms at query time.

See: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory

After you move synonyms to the index analyzer chain, check that they are working with the Analysis page in the admin UI.

Comment: Does that mean I should delete my index and re-index after I establish the synonyms?

Comment: The Analysis page does not seem to be reading my schema. The SynonymFilterFactory is still showing up for the "query" and references "synonyms.txt". I have no idea why it's reading synonyms.txt because I just looked up "synonyms.txt" in the Schema page and found no matches.

Comment: You can view your schema.xml through the admin UI, look for the SCHEMA link at the top. You may have to walk through the config files starting with the -Dsolr.solr.home location you set for Java. That should point you to the schema in use.

Comment: If you use explicit synonym mappings ("i-pod, i pod => ipod"), don't you also need to use SynonymFilterFactory at query time?

Comment: @WalterUnderwood Please see my edit. The solr home seems correct, no?

Comment: The schema has <analyzer type="query">. The synonyms should be in the <analyzer type="index"> filter chain. When you have both "i-pod" and "ipod" in the index for each document, the query can contain either one. You only need to expand synonyms once.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Walter Underwood is good, but incomplete.

Whether you use the SynonymFilterFactory at index or query time [depends on your default operator](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10102).

So, let's say we have a synonym file with this entry:

```
5,five
```

If your default operator is `OR` (which is the default default operator), then you should set up your synonyms on the **query** filter. This way a query for "5" will be passed to the backend as a query for "5" OR "five", say, and the backend would respond appropriately. At the same time, you can make changes to your synonym file without reindexing, and your index is smaller since it doesn't have to have so many tokens.

However, if you change the default operator to `AND`, you should set up your synonyms on the **index** filter instead. If you don't, a query for "5" would go to the backend as "5" AND "five", and it would not match the documents that it's expected to. This, alas, makes the index bigger, and also means new synonyms require complete reindexes.

Note: The [documentation for this](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory) is currently wrong, leaving out all these details.