# SOLR - How to get results from Madonna if the query is Madona

Tags: solr

I have a catalog of musics that contains the songs's names and artist's names, when someone is searching "madona" I would like them find Madonna's songs, does not matter if they only write "madona" with a single "n".

Somewhere I read about synonyms, then I put a file with a list of synonyms, something like this:

```
madona => madonna
metalica => metallica
```

And this in schema.xml:

```
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="lang/synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
```

but there are not results.

What can I do?, Please help!

Comment: Use the SynonymFilterFactory only at index time, not query time. After this changes please do reindex your data to be displayed in search result. See this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998480/how-to-use-synonymfilterfactory-in-solr

Answer (score 1):

I can think of these alternatives:

1. Synonyms are already mentioned, the downside is that you need to know them in advance
2. Phonetic analyzers, [there are several options here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PhoneticFilterFactory). I think this would work best for artist names and such, as wrong spellings are more common
3. Using fuzzy search, [see the doc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches) should work too

Answer (score 0):

Synonyms is one possible approach, but it's most appropriate when you want to substitute or append other query terms at runtime. For example, if someone were searching for furniture and entered the keyword "couch", there might logically be a synonym for "sofa" that could be included as well. That's the intended use of synonyms.

When dealing with mis-spellings and/or typos, those scenarios are often best handled through stemming. Stemming takes a term (token) and reduces it to an often abbreviated, core representation of the word. Different analyzers can employ a variety of token stemmers to reduce text to something that can yield more effective searches, such as "madonna" and "madona" referring to the same document.

Stemming refers back to the field of linguistic analysis, so it's not a quick-hit learning cycle. That said, you can try out the different analyzers contained in Solr through the Admin tool. Depending on the version of Solr you're using, the menu contains an option for "Analysis". This page permits you to select any of the underlying Solr field types (as well as any in your own schema), plug in some text for both the index and query, and see what the analyzer generates. You may not find exactly what you're looking for, but Solr's configurability permits you to wire these together in different combinations. Once you have that background under your belt, you can construct those to meet your specific use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to all!

I found something interesting about synonyms: The list should include tokens not words, so even using synonyms, did not have the expected result, since the indexed token for madonna is Madonn and the token generated for Madonna query is madon, so in the synonym list would include:

```
madon => madonn
```

Only in this way got results.

As for using another parser, which is currently using::

```
<!-- Portuguese -->
<fieldType name="text_pt" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index"> 
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_pt.txt" format="snowball" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Portuguese"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_pt.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_pt.txt" format="snowball" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Portuguese"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_pt.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

[image]